# Bootstrap CDN over-rides my custom CSS files

Tags: theming

I have a modest site that I was hired to help customize with some CSS features, however I am noticing a problem.

Bootstrap has its own mini-file that tells it what to style its navigation bars with and at the moment, because of that, my nav bar text is grey. Its contrast compared what the site owner wants is very poor and so I attempted to change this to black.

However in doing so, because I am using CDN, bootstrap files seem to override my custom CSS template files. Is there a way to resolve this issue? I have searched for answers but have yet to find any, please help. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom css needs to be more targeted to override the default boostrap css. On line 38 replace ".navbar-nav" with the following:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a
```

Comment: I went into the file and added what you put down listed, but updated it to stylesheets, thinking you put styleshoots by mistake? But this did not seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yep, meant to put "stylesheets" - thanks. Did you flush the cache? Also, how is the boostrap css being loaded? What theme is the site using?

Comment: Yes I flushed the cache. I am using the bootstrap theme, and the bootstrap.css.min is being loaded via CDN. 

When I inspect it in firefox, it says the bootstrap.min.css is the "main" css file, while my css file is just inherited.

Comment: Strange, I have a site that uses the Bootstrap theme and adding the css/style.css line above overrides whatever I tell it to. Is it possible that you aren't targeting the nav bar text directly enough? Is your custom css file organized in the file name and directory structure listed above?

Comment: I added my code as images so you could take a better look at it. I know the CSS file works because i can change elements like the jumbo tron from white text to red text no problem. However, changing the nav-bar does not work, so i'm assuming it may be due to lack of proper targeting. How would I target it correctly?

Comment: On line 38, try replacing ".navbar-nav" with ".nav .navbar .navbar-default" and clear the cache. ".navbar-default" has many custom css classes added to it.

Comment: I tried it, and no luck. I don't know what's wrong. Its like bootstrap has the navbar so heavily customized that any specific css I write will not override it because theirs is more specific.

Comment: One last try, on line 38 replace ".navbar-nav" with ".navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a". This is very targeted.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That seemed to solve the underlying issue. I guess when it comes to navbars, I have to be very specific, but I do not have the bootstrap lingo down yet, so targeting for me is going to take some practice!

Comment: If you need help determining CSS selector precedence, https://specificity.keegan.st will show you how a selector's components determine its specificity.